# Insert text when new related field added filemaker 11

Tags: filemaker

I have been tasked with adding some functionality to an old Filemaker 11 Database.

I have a table with a portal to a related field. Whenever an entry is added to the portal I am to insert some text into  description field to prompt users to record some specific information related to that portal field.

I have set up some global variables to hold the required text and in the case of a normal field it is quite easy to trigger the text insert based on the value in a field. What I am having trouble figuring out is how to trigger the insert text based on the values in a portal.

Suggestions?

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can insert a default value into a field by using the field's [auto-enter options](http://www.filemaker.com/help/11/fmp/html/create_db.8.18.html#1029444). If you want this to happen only upon record's creation, leave the `Do not replace existing value (if any)` option checked.

---

I did not understand this part:

> how to trigger the insert text based on the values in a portal.

You need to explain how exactly the inserted text should be "*based on the values in a portal*".